# How do I fix this undefined array key?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

This is the error currently show. Below The first code I save as details.php and the second on as details.html

Warning: Undefined array key "first_name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\children_math\detail2.php on line 12

Warning: Undefined array key "last_name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\children_math\detail2.php on line 13

Warning: Undefined array key "email" in C:\xampp\htdocs\children_math\detail2.php on line 14

Warning: Undefined array key "age" in C:\xampp\htdocs\children_math\detail2.php on line 15
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO details (first_name, last_name, email, age) VALUES ('', '', '', ''). Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`record`.`details`, CONSTRAINT `details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

````
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "record");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
// Escape user inputs for security
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['last_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['age']);
 
// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO details (first_name, last_name, email, age) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$age')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 
// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add Record Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="detail2.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lastName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="emailAddress">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="ages">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="ages">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Try [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function to fix this error.

Comment: for $email = $_POST['email']; ?

Comment: are you sure that the POST is getting the value successfully? The form must have the  attribute of method="POST"

Comment: @TanYiJing im not very sure sir, as i just learn php and html for few months

Comment: @TanYiJing is it wrong coding?

Comment: try to add your front-end code in the post so that we can further investigate\

Comment: did u set up your DB correctly? Try typing localhost/phpmyadmin to verify your DB connection as well as there is details table in your DB.

Comment: Does this form submit to the same page or to another script?

Comment: You should not be using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` anymore.  Prepared statements are the modern standard.

Answer (score 4):

i had a similar problem; i solved it by checking the file referenced in the error and the line. In your case its details2.php.In my case that error was triggered because the variable names $variable_name = $_POST['key_value']; were initialized outside my if(isset($_POST['Register'])) block. All i did was include it immediately after my if(condition)block like so;

```
if (isset($_POST['Register'])) {
    
// receive all input values from the form
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$phone_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone_number']);
$email =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$Church =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['church']);
$Password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']); //encrypt password
$Password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['passwordConf']);
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(50)); // generate unique token
```

// form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
// by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array

```
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $errors['name'] = 'Name required';
    }
    ....
```

Comment: This worked for me, using `empty($_POST` so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your form has the method attribute set to post

```
<form action="your_page.php" method="post">
  <label for="email">Email :</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="emailInput"><br><br>
</form>
```

At `your_page.php`, you can get the value by `$email = $_POST['emailInput'];`

The string(emailInput) inside the `$_POST['emailInput'];` is the `name` of your input tag.

Comment: CREATE TABLE users(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE details(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    age VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

my table is like this Mr Tan, i want to link with users table.

Comment: I can't find any issue with the coding above hence the only problem might be the linkage between your web application and the DB (PhpMyAdmin)